# XML/XSL: how to compare two nodes and set value of another node depending on the comparison?

Tags: xml, xslt, compare, nodes

A question about XML & XSL
(I am using sharepoint 2007)

How do you compare two nodes?

In the example below I want to compare 'promotionprice' with 'price'.

If the 'promotionprice' equals or is greater than 'price' then 'OK' should be "NO".
If the 'promotionprice' lesser than 'price' then 'OK' should be "YES".

I am not sure I am using the correct syntax because in sharepoint it does not work, it always gives YES.

```
XML example:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<catalog>
<cd>
<title>Empire Burlesque</title> 
<artist>Bob Dylan</artist> 
<country>USA</country> 
<company>Columbia</company> 
<price>10.90</price>
<promotionprice>15.00</promotionprice>
<year>1985</year> 
<OK>Yes</OK>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>Hide your heart</title> 
<artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist> 
<country>UK</country> 
<company>CBS Records</company> 
<price>9.90</price> 
<promotionprice>5.00</promotionprice>
<year>1988</year> 
<OK>Yes</OK>
</cd>
</catalog>


XSL example:
...
<!-- title node -->
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
</td>
<!-- artist node -->
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="@artist"/>
</td>
...
<!-- OK node -->
<td>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="promotionprice &gt;= price">
<xsl:value-of select="'NO'"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="'YES'"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</td>

WANTED RESULT:
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>Empire Burlesque</td>
  <td>Bob Dylan</td>
  <td>USA</td>
  <td>Columbia</td>
  <td>10.90</td>
  <td>15.00</td>
  <td>1985</td>
  <td>NO</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Hide your heart</td>
  <td>Bonnie Tyler</td>
  <td>UK</td>
  <td>CBS Records</td>
  <td>9.90</td>
  <td>5.00</td>
  <td>1988</td>
  <td>YES</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks A LOT in advance!

Comment: Please, *edit* the question and provide the exact wanted result from the transformation.

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <table border="1">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </table>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="cd">
   <tr><xsl:apply-templates/></tr>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="title|artist">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="OK">
  <td>
   <xsl:value-of select=
    "substring('YESNO', 4 -3*(../price >= ../promotionprice),3)"/>
  </td>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <promotionprice>15.00</promotionprice>
        <year>1985</year>
        <OK>Yes</OK>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <promotionprice>5.00</promotionprice>
        <year>1988</year>
        <OK>Yes</OK>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

**produces what I *guess* is the wanted result:**

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>Empire Burlesque</td>
      <td>Bob Dylan</td>
      <td>NO</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Hide your heart</td>
      <td>Bonnie Tyler</td>
      <td>YES</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: +1 for the `substring()` instead of an `xsl:choose`. @dee-ln - If you change `match="title|artist"` to `match="*"` and remove `<xsl:template match="text()"/>` you'll get exactly the output you're looking for.